# Protect high voltage little currents

Tags: resistors, mains, fuses

**Short question:**
Are there alternatives to very low currents fuses? I need something that breaks at about 6 mA. and I cannot find anything like that.

**Long question:**
I am trying to detect mains (230VAC) using HCPL3700 ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/HCPL3700-1010474.pdf)) and ESP32. This is the diagram I found on the internet:

[image]

And this is what I am planning to do, which seems to work. **Sens2** is the 230V live input to the circuit, and ESPSense is going to the ESP32 IO pin.

[image]

Based on my calculations, my resistors can hold < 8mA ([Resistor Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810301127_UNI-ROYAL-Uniroyal-Elec-25121WJ0393T4E_C25723.pdf))
[image]

So If I add a 150mA fuse (smallest I found on JLCPCB), the resistors will burn before the fuse.
The problem is that it is not easy to find SMD resistors with more than 1W, neither fuses with less than 8mA trip current

Is there any other way of protecting this?

Comment: Why do you need to add a fuse? Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: #1 - you're calculating the maximum current incorrectly. You don't have a single 2W resistor, you have 2 x 1W resistors in series, so do the calculation for a single resistor (your result should be about 5mA). #2 You're wasting your effort. What failure mode are you actually trying to prevent? How would it come about that too much current flows through those resistors?

Comment: Thanks @brhans. Why is my calculation wrong? Since each resistor will drop 115v, then 1 resistor is 1W/115v, which is the same as 2W/230V. What am I missing?

Comment: @Andyaka, I was trying to protect against a short of a resistor, the HCPL chip doing something weird,  the input voltage getting too high, or somebody putting a finger in there. But yours is actually a really good first question, what should I protect against? :)

Comment: I've never seen an HCPL input fail short.  Usually it's the logic side which fails.

Comment: Do the math. You'll find that 8.6mA through a 39k resistor dissipates almost 2.9W in that resistor.

Comment: Thanks @rdtsc! This is my first HCPL circuit, and I have never actually seen it anywhere besides some internet theoretical proposed schemas. Do you have any example of a real use I could look at to see how it is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tricky issue. If it wasn't mains I could have said 'use an active current limiter' (in many case a JFET would do the trick) or something like that.

The problem is safety: you need to use *safety rated* components and do an analysis of what happens when they break to avoid fires and other unpleasant things. The HCPL costs a lot since it's designed for safety, too.

For example a fuse is *guaranteed* to fail open. A resistor doesn't and that's the reason for *two* resistors in series. Even if one fail shorts the other one somewhat still do its job.

What are you looking for this application is a fusing resistor (which is guaranteed to blow open when overloaded). Most probably you'll have use a THT one for that job.

Comment: Resistors in series are to achieve sufficient voltage rating and are not placed that way in case one fails. Resistors can be assumed to be infallible if rated correctly and from a decent supplier having a decent quality system.

Comment: Maybe it's for another standard… I remember we had to put two series resistor for that reason years ago. Probably slightly different circumstances or some corner case. Found it: it's for atex zener barriers. Either you buy the holy certified expensive infallible resistor or you put two in series and do the failure analysis for the short case.

Comment: Infallible resistors (ATEX related) are just normal resistors except you apply sufficient margin on power and voltage. A resistor is infallible by application and not by supplier.